# Gradshteyn Rational function problem

Tags: integration

I am trying this for the last few days but no way out.
can anybody show me some light on this integral?

$\int{ (Mx + N) \over(A +2Bx+Cx^2)^{p}}dx={(NB-MA)+(NC-MB)x \over(2(p-1)(AC-B^2)(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p-1}}+{(2p-3)(NC-MB) \over 2(p-1)(AC-B^2)} \int {dx \over (A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p-1} }
$

Comment: Please carefully proofread your question, it makes no sense as it is.

Comment: differentiate the RHS and simplify ... hopefully you will get the intergrand of the LHS (when you put the power of $p$ in the denominator)

Comment: $p$ is an integer > 1?

Comment: yeah, p must be greater than 1.

Answer (score 2):

Right, lets start with typo corrections
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{Mx+N}{(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{\color{red}{p}}} =
 \frac{(NB-MA)+(NC-MB)x}{2(p-1)(AC-B^2)(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p-1}}+ 
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{\color{red}{(2p-3)}(NC-MB)}{2(p-1)(AC-B^2)} \int\frac{dx}{(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p-1}}
\end{eqnarray*}
We shall show this, by differentiating the RHS and showing that it gives the integrand of the LHS.
First note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p-1}} = \frac{-2(p-1)(B+Cx)}{(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Differentiating the RHS gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{-(B+Cx)((NB-MA)+(NC-MB)x}{(AC-B^2)(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p}}+\frac{(NC-MB)}{2(p-1)(AC-B^2)(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p-1}}+\frac{(NC-MB)(2p-3)}{2(p-1)(AC-B^2)(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p-1}}
\end{eqnarray*}
add the second & third terms gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{-(B+Cx)((NB-MA)+(NC-MB)x)}{(AC-B^2)(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p}}+\frac{(NC-MB)(1+2p-3)}{2(p-1)(AC-B^2)(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p-1}}
\end{eqnarray*}
cancal $2(p-1)$ and multiply the top by $(A+2Bx+Cx^2)$ and add these terms gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{-(B+Cx)((NB-MA)+(NC-MB)x)+(NC-MB)(A+2Bx+Cx^2)}{(AC-B^2)(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p}}
\end{eqnarray*}
After a little algebra in the numerator & cancelling a the factor $AC-B^2$ top and bottom we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{Mx+N}{(AC-B^2)(A+2Bx+Cx^2)^{p}}
\end{eqnarray*}
precisely the integrand of the LHS, as required.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there any way to prove the RHS from LHS?